# Variable Buttons setOnClickListener crashing

Tags: android, variables, button, crash

I have the following code:

```
    LinearLayout myScrollLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrolllinear);
    Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();

    // loop for every file in raw folder
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

    Button[] buttons = new Button[fields.length];
    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {
        final int counti = count;
        buttons[count] = new Button(this);
        buttons[count].setText("Wallpaper " + count);
        buttons[count].setId(100+count);

        int animId = res.getIdentifier("anim" + count, "raw",
                getBaseContext().getPackageName());

        buttons[count].setBackgroundResource(animId);

        buttons[count].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSetWallpaper(counti);
            }
        });
        myScrollLinearLayout.addView(buttons[count]);
    }
```

The images are fine but their is a problem with the listener
as it is crashing at line 
                    onSetWallpaper(counti);

Comment: what is the crash you're getting, you need to post LogCat or something, or else we have no idea what kind of error is breaking your code. In saying that, its probably something in your onSetWallpaper(int) method

Comment: tanks alot it was in onSetWallpaper !!

Comment: **Post the LogCat and onSetWallpaper() method** otherwise we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @user2365568 the `getFields` returns an array